# How can I use Labels which are created in a custom cell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I have 3 Labels in my prototype cell of a tableview. I want to connect them to my code and give them a name that I can use them for the cellforrow method. I connected them to the code ,but I cannot use them in this method. Does anyone know how to this?

Comment: Congratulations on starting your first app. Before it's too late, please don't use Storyboard and use XIB instead.

Comment: @EdwardAnthony Thank you. Whats the difference between XIB and Storyboard??

Comment: With XIB, you put one view per XIB, but with storyboard, you could put a lot of views per storyboard. When the application get big, there will be a lot of views, and this will cause annoying lag when you're viewing the storyboard. Not only that, if you're using GIT for teamwork, there will be a merge conflict that will make you can't open the storyboard at all.

Comment: @EdwardAnthony Ahh okey. I already started with my app with Storyboard. But it is just a little App for my school and hast just 5 ViewControllers :D

Comment: You can easily separate your storyboard into multiple files, I would even say it's bad practice to have all your view controllers in a single file if you have more than just a few screens. Your school app with 5 view controllers will be fine.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Thank you all for the help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Create the custom table view cell with a separate class

2.Create the UILabel as the property of custom table view cell

3.Then you can use the below code for access the UI label of your custom table view cell

```
 let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell

customCell.yourLabel.text = “Success”
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much. What do you mean with a separate class. Sorry for the question but thats going to be my first App :D

Comment: create the separate XIB file for custom table view cell with a new swift class,

Comment: in this question "cel" to cell,  Should be

Comment: Sorry for bothering you but I got another question: I created the custom cell but how can I  create the UILabel as the property of custom table view cell?

Comment: https://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/   - refer this tutorial

Comment: @TheClubApp Cool